# parse XML and create defensive copy in getter - Java JABX

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file using java JABX and create a set of objects. I have a class that I want to map xml to:

```
public class Dash implements Serializable {

    private List<ViewBlock> viewBlocks = new ArrayList<ViewBlock>();

    public List<ViewBlock> getViewBlocks() {
        return viewBlocks; //  ---> this works          
        //return new ArrayList<ViewBlock>(viewBlocks); ---> this doesn't
    }
    public void setViewBlocks(List<ViewBlock> viewBlocks) {
        this.viewBlocks.clear();
        this.viewBlocks.addAll(viewBlocks);
    }
}
```

It works fine if inside the getter method I have `return viewBlocks` but when I use the second option `return new ArrayList<ViewBlock>(viewBlocks)` my array list is empty. I need it to return a copy of the array and parse the xml, is this possible ?

Comment: Are you sure that viewBlocks is not empty, when you use a defensive copying? Try to log the size of the original viewBlocks and the copied viewBlocks before returning it

Comment: original and copied viewBlocks are empty if I use defensive copying

Comment: So I guess the issue is not related to your getter, since it is supposed to work correctly (it creates an empty list from an empty list). Try to debug further and see why the data is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing via adding a null check and ensure initialization happens.

```
 public class Dash implements Serializable {

    private List<ViewBlock> viewBlocks = new ArrayList<ViewBlock>();

    public List<ViewBlock> getViewBlocks() {

      if (viewBlocks== null) {
            numbers = new ArrayList<ViewBlock>();
        }          
        return viewBlocks;
    }
    public void setViewBlocks(List<ViewBlock> viewBlocks) {
        this.viewBlocks.clear();
        this.viewBlocks.addAll(viewBlocks);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will never be null since it's already initialized `private List<ViewBlock> viewBlocks = new ArrayList<ViewBlock>();`